# Why to define functions rather than include a file

Tags: c, function, include

I was making a code and I had like 5 include files in there, I was defining functions in this file and then realized why should not I just make separate `header files` for all the functions and then just include them in a file at last. But, I have seen that this is not done usually. Why not? Is there a particular disadvantage of doing this?

Comment: Which programming language? Could you post a little code here?

Comment: I am talking about C. And I am asking this question in general. Is there a disadvantage of doing what I mentioned?

Comment: That is a common practice. Why do you think that this is not done usually?

Comment: May be because this will take a lot of preprocessor actions. Means is it good that our preprocessor keeps replacing a lot of code from the files. Does this now slow down the execution?

Comment: No, you misunderstood my question. On which system kinds are you working so that you have an impression that this is not done usually?

Comment: @nalply- you can provide him with the straight answer rather than asking out-of-context questions. Even common practices have principles behind them. And C is a language not some pre-historic ritual.

Comment: @Abhineet, I don't have an answer. I am trying to figure out an answer.

Comment: It depends upon the programmers and the standard if they are following.If you want you can no body is there to stop you.

Comment: @Downvoter- Please comment here after downvoting. Question publisher should know the reason for getting down voted, so that he/she can take steps to improve the question.

Comment: No, this didn't slow execution and as nalply says it's a common practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a real answer, because the question has a wrong assumption:

> But, I have seen that this is not done usually.

This is not true. This is a common practice. A good example is [ffmpeg.h](http://www.lavrsen.dk/svn/motion/tags/3.2.9/ffmpeg.h). The header is a front-end to an extensive library.

The argument of long compilation times is bogus. Today the systems are very fast. This is only important for really huge systems, but I really don't think that you work with them. I never encountered such systems myself.

And compilation times aren't execution times. This is another misconception.

For your convenience the whole code of ffmpeg.h:

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_FFMPEG_H_
#define _INCLUDE_FFMPEG_H_

#ifdef HAVE_FFMPEG
#include <avformat.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/* Define a codec name/identifier for timelapse videos, so that we can
 * differentiate between normal mpeg1 videos and timelapse videos.
 */
#define TIMELAPSE_CODEC "mpeg1_tl"

struct ffmpeg {
#ifdef HAVE_FFMPEG
    AVFormatContext *oc;
    AVStream *video_st;
    AVCodecContext *c;

    AVFrame *picture;       /* contains default image pointers */
    uint8_t *video_outbuf;
    int video_outbuf_size;

    void *udata;            /* U & V planes for greyscale images */
    int vbr;                /* variable bitrate setting */
    char codec[20];         /* codec name */
#else
    int dummy;
#endif
};

/* Initialize FFmpeg stuff. Needs to be called before ffmpeg_open. */
void ffmpeg_init(void);

/* Open an mpeg file. This is a generic interface for opening either an mpeg1 or
 * an mpeg4 video. If non-standard mpeg1 isn't supported (FFmpeg build > 4680), 
 * calling this function with "mpeg1" as codec results in an error. To create a
 * timelapse video, use TIMELAPSE_CODEC as codec name.
 */
struct ffmpeg *ffmpeg_open(
    char *ffmpeg_video_codec, 
    char *filename, 
    unsigned char *y,    /* YUV420 Y plane */
    unsigned char *u,    /* YUV420 U plane */
    unsigned char *v,    /* YUV420 V plane */
    int width,
    int height, 
    int rate,            /* framerate, fps */
    int bps,             /* bitrate; bits per second */
    int vbr              /* variable bitrate */
    );

/* Puts the image pointed to by the picture member of struct ffmpeg. */
void ffmpeg_put_image(struct ffmpeg *);

/* Puts the image defined by u, y and v (YUV420 format). */
void ffmpeg_put_other_image(
    struct ffmpeg *ffmpeg, 
    unsigned char *y, 
    unsigned char *u, 
    unsigned char *v
    );

/* Closes the mpeg file. */
void ffmpeg_close(struct ffmpeg *);

/*Deinterlace the image. */
void ffmpeg_deinterlace(unsigned char *, int, int);

/*Setup an avcodec log handler. */
void ffmpeg_avcodec_log(void *, int, const char *, va_list);

#endif /* _INCLUDE_FFMPEG_H_ */
```

Comment: Now that's an answer with facts and examples. Nice work nalply. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

Some people argue that putting functions in a separate file and including them through a header adds some overhead to the project and increases compilation (not execution) time. Although strictly speaking this is true, in practice the increased compilation time is negligible.

My take on the issue is more based on the purpose of the functions. I am against putting a single function per file with an associate header as this quickly becomes a mess to maintain. I do not think that putting everybody together in a single file is a good approach either (also a mess to maintain, although for different reasons).

My opinion is that the ideal trade off is to look at the purpose of the functions. You should ask yourself whether the functions can be used somewhere else or not. In other words, can these functions be used as a library for a series of common tasks in other programs? If yes, these functions should be grouped in a single file. Use as many files as you have general tasks. For instance, all functions to perform numerical integration in one file, all functions to handle file i/o in another, all functions to deal with strings in a third file and so on. In this way your libraries are consistent.

Finally, I would place a function that performs a task only meaningful for a specific program into the same file of the `main` function. For instance any function whose purpose is to initialize a series of variables.

But most of all, you should take any advice just as an advice. In the end of the day you should adopt the approach that makes your (or your team) development the most productive.

Comment: Compilation time is a trifle, I don't think anyone should let that argument affect their program design decisions. The arguments made about maintenance and code re-usage are far more important to consider.

Comment: @Lundin - I agree that compilation time is not an argument that should weight in the decision. However, you can still see it popping up in discussions. My point was, it is true but not not worth taking into account it when deciding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should only make one "super-include-header" if you are writing some sort of API or library and want to make it easy for the user of that library to access the functions inside. The Windows OS API is the most obvious example of this, where one #include  gives you access of thousands upon thousands of functions.

But even when writing such libraries, you should be wary of "super-headers". The reason why you should try to avoid them is related to program design. Object-oriented design dictates that you should strive to make isolated, autonomous modules that focus on their own task without knowing or caring about the rest of the program.

The rationale behind that design rule, is to reduce the phenomenon known as *tight [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)*, where every module is heavily dependant on other modules. Computer science research ([like this study](http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=11923), for example) shows that tight coupling combined with complexity leads to far more software errors, and also far more severe errors. If a program with tight coupling gets a bug in one module, the bug might escalate throughout the whole program and cause disaster. While a bug in one autonomous module with loose coupling only leads to that particular module failing.

Each time you include a header file, you create a dependency between your program and that header file. So while it is tempting to just make one file that includes everything, you should avoid this, as it would create tight coupling between all modules in the project. It will also expose the modules to each other's global name space, possibly leading to more name space collisions with identical variable names etc.

Tight coupling is also, aside from the safety concerns, very annoying when you link/build your program. With tight coupling, suddenly your database module cannot work if something completely unrelated, like the GUI library isn't linked.

Comment: +1 Didn't think about coupling. We are all here to learn.